# How to save jpa entities on application shutdown?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have a service which handles CRUD operations for entities using H2 database. Previously during testing phase I used to have a csv file which "acted" as a database and upon application shutdown I saved all in-memory changes to entities to this csv file. Now I want to do the same, but for some reason I am not hitting any breakpoints in my `onExit()` method and therefore not saving data on application shutdown. I am still working out proper logic for selecting *which* entities to save, but for now I just want to be able to automatically save when I press Stop 'Application' button in Intellij.

```
@Component
public class MangaDataProvider {

  private static MangaService mangaService;

  @Autowired
  public MangaDataProvider(MangaService mangaService) {
    MangaDataProvider.mangaService = mangaService;
  }

  @PreDestroy
  public static void onExit() {
    mangaService.saveAll();
  }
}
```

And then I have a `onExit()` method in `Application`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements AppShellConfigurator {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LaunchUtil.launchBrowserInDevelopmentMode(SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args));
  }

  @PreDestroy
  public void onExit() {
    MangaDataProvider.onExit();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that the shutdown hooks will be executed. They have a very limited time to execute. That means you code may be partially executed. You can try to add a Print statement, or a debug breakpoint. You will observe that the first statement is executed because it's super fast, but there is no time left to execute the rest of the method.
I good practice would be to call a service or an endpoint which "prepares" (in your case, it will persist your data) your application for shutdown. You call this service/endpoint then, when execution completed, you can safely terminate the application.
Many server application have a "prepare for shutdown" endpoint. Per example Jenkins ;)